# nil slice when passed as interface is not nil! Why? (golang)

Tags: go, null

See this playground: http://play.golang.org/p/nWHmlw1W01

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i []int = nil
    yes(i) // output: true
    no(i)  // output: false
}

func yes(thing []int) {
    fmt.Println(thing == nil)
}

func no(thing interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(thing == nil)
}
```

Why the difference in output between the two functions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Admittedly, it's somewhat of a quirk, but there's an explanation for it.

Imagine an `interface{}` variable as a struct composed of two fields: one is the type and another is the data. (`[]int` and `nil`). Actually, it looks just like that in the Go runtime.

```
struct Iface                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                              
    Itab*   tab;                                                                                                               
    void*   data;                                                                                                              
};
```

When you pass your nil slice to `yes`, only `nil` is passed as the value, so your comparison boils down to `nil == nil`.

Meanwhile, calling `no` automatically wraps your variable in an `interface{}` type and the call becomes something akin to `no(interface{[]int, nil})`. So the comparison in `no` could be seen as `interface{[]int, nil} == nil`, which turns out to be false in go.

The issue is actually explained in [the Go FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error).

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the clarification--I should have gone to the docs. So the nil check in this case would have to be something like this: http://play.golang.org/p/M_z1I5iGeW

Comment: http://research.swtch.com/interfaces provides more details, if you're interested.

Comment: Txg golang... writing programs with heavy use of interfaces is a nightmare

Answer (score 1):

To add to @justinas' answer, if you need to compare the value **inside** the `interface{}` value, you can use `reflect.ValueOf.IsNil()` method which would report if value **inside** the `interface{}` is nil.

```golang
func main() {
    var a []int = nil
    var ai interface{} = a

    r1 := a == nil // true
    r2 := ai == nil // false, interface is not nil

    vo := reflect.ValueOf(ai).IsNil() // true, value inside interface is nil!
}
```